# Express Layouts EJS with different file paths

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am just starting with Express and express-ejs-layouts.  I have a layout.ejs file that has the common parts of my web app.  This works great for pages that are at `http://localhost/path1/path2`, but I would also like to use this for the root index page of my app (i.e.: `http://localhost/`

The problem is the links for the CSS and JS files:

```
<link href="../../stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This doesn't work for `http://localhost/`

Should I break this out and add it to each view template with the correct pathing?  How have people done this in the past?

Comment: You can use absolute URLs for static files (eg. `href="/public/css/` ), to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks - works great and simple.  If you want to post this as the answer I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute URLs for static files (eg. `href="/public/css/"` ) to avoid this issue.

For Node.js/Express.js web applications, it's convenient to create a `public` folder at the root, where you put all your static files.